# Automatically change the version of only assembly which has code changes in Dot Net

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, .net-assembly, automatic-differentiation, assemblyversions

I am creating patch for my application to deploy small changes to customer. In my application I have 100 .CSProject. Out of 100 library I made code changes in class library A, B, C and Library D is calling to A,B and C library. So Is there any way when I build my application then It should change the version of only A,B,C and D library which have changes. Manually I can change but I need any automatic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So Is there any way when I build my application then It should change
>   the version of only A,B,C and D library which have changes. Manually I
>   can change but I need any automatic way.

Actually, `Directory Build.targets` file can probably realize it. When you create a file called Directory.Build.targets, it can search and act on all projects in the current folder and subordinates. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#search-scope) about its search scope.  `Directory Build.targets` is pretty much like `Directory Build.props`. And `Directory Build.targets` executes after build while `Directory Build.props` executes before the build starts.

**In your situation**, you want to overwrite property **Version**, you should use `Directory Build.targets`.

**Then** when you're building a project, it automatically puts content in the scope of the project.

**Solution**

**1)** create a file called `Directory Build.targets` file under your solution or upper level directory of 100 projects.

**2)** add these into `Directory Build.targets` file:

```
<Target Name="change_property" AfterTargets="CoreCompile">
<PropertyGroup>
<Version>xxxxx</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

**3)** Then you can set all changed projects' version to the same version that you wish.

And this function makes the same property changes for all the changed projects.

**You should Note that it has a flaw**

But you should not modify other related projects(code changes or add new item, picture or anything else) If you change unrelated projects, this feature also changes the **version** of unrelated projects. This is a special feature of **CoreCompile** target.

**Suggestion**

**Therefore**, you should pay attention not to modifying other projects or you could use Alt+A to select all projects-->unload project and then reload required projects and modify them in case any other unrelated projects are modified.

**Or** try to put these required projects into a new folder called `Modified Projects` under the solution folder(which exists `xxx.sln` file) and then put `Directory Build.targets` into `Modified Projects` folder.

-----------------Use other methods like this to avoid this situation.

**Update 1**

**1)** If your projects are in the same solution folder, then you can create a file called `Directory.Build.targets`.

[image]

It will work on all items in the current folder and its secondary directory.

And add my sample code in this file:

```
<Project>
<Target Name="change_property" AfterTargets="CoreCompile">
    <PropertyGroup>
    <Version>xxxxx</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

And then you can modify your nuget projects, when you finishing your related projects, you can build your solution or use MSBuild.exe to `build xxx.sln` and this file will be executed automatically and will change the version of modified nuget projects.

Hope it could help you and any other feedback will be expected.

**Update 2**

Please try to change to use in `Directory.Build.targets` and it will work under the whole solution to apply to every `verison` number.

```
 <Project>
    <Target Name="change_property" AfterTargets="CoreCompile">
        <PropertyGroup>
        <Version>xxxxx</Version>
        </PropertyGroup>
        </Target>
    </Project>
<PropertyGroup>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

And make sure that `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` in `Directory.Build.targets`. Otherwise it will fail. So please remove this node in `xxx.csorj` file and add `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` in `Directory.Build.targets`.

Comment: **@Perry Qian** As per my understating, this is again manual process. I have to include only changed project in build. But I need some automatic process which can track if Project A got change then It should change the version of A as well as Project D which is referencing project A.

Comment: Actually, `Directory Build.targets` is the equivalent of an automated script. It affects all projects in your current directory or two-level directory, and when your project changes, it will automatically change the version number when building. So my steps is to create such automated script and you can try it.

Comment: Hey @Perry, Could you please help me out with any sample which apply when I build .sln file using msbuild. So I can get clear Idea on which you mentioned.

Comment: If it works or not, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: I made changes and ran msbuild but still its not change. It is showing version number which I set from command line using msbuild. Ill give you brief example. In Application I have 3 Solution name as (SolA, SolB, SolC) & I have common lib name as Common.lib. in SolA an Application Name as AWindowsService and in SolB an application name as BWinForm both are using this Commob.lib assembly.Now I made change in Common.lib then It should change the version only of Common.lib, AWindowService and BWinForm proejct and for other lib and project it should set the version which I am setting from Msbuild.

Comment: It is not working as expected. But yes its gave me help to chnage the version in current and sab dir.